# Can I uniformly sample from $N$ distinct elements, where $N$ is unknown but finite?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

I have access to a list of $N$ elements, but the value of $N$ is unknown. The elements arrive one by one, and never repeat. I want to sample $n$ of these elements as uniformly as possible, as I have storage only enough to save $n$ elements, but not all of the (unknown) $N$. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: In this case $N$ would be a random variable. What does this sentence mean "I don't have storage that can save n elements but not all of the N"?

Comment: if i have storage for all N elements, I could just save them as I see them, and sample them after receiving. Essentially gives me the number of N.

Comment: but your sentence says: "have no storage for n but have no storage for N" - I don't know what the "but" means.

Comment: oh, thanks for pointing that out, I edited.

Comment: If you know the distribution of N, you could approximate random uniform sampling...

Comment: @mathse, can you please give em an example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, if you knew that $N$ is between $90$ and $110$ with highest prob. at $100$, I would select each element with prob. $n/100$?

Comment: @mathse, are you suggesting to use mean as the estimation for N ?

Comment: This wouldn't be the worst approximation, I think, depending on the distribution of $N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can if you can use another word of memory.  Start by keeping the first $n$ objects.  When object $n+1$ comes along, throw a random number and keep it object $n+1$ with probability $\frac n{n+1}$  If you keep it, throw another random number between $1$ and $n$ and replace that item.  You should be able to convince yourself that the sample is uniform-that each item is kept with probability $\frac n{n+1}$.  Now proceed by induction.  Say you have a random sample of $n$ elements out of $n+k$ (so each is present with probability $\frac n{n+k}$) when element $n+k+1$ comes along.  Keep it with probability $\frac n{n+k+1}$ and if you keep it, replace a random element of your pool.  You just need to store how many elements you have seen so far.

Comment: Yeah, this is my intuition, very nice formalize it. !Thanks